# DICOM to NIFTI conversion

Tags: python, image-processing, medical-imaging, nifti

I have converted **DICOM** files to **NIFTI** format using `dicom2nifti.dicom_series_to_nifti(case,output_path)`.
But when I see labels/ground truths on the NIFTI image they appear horizontally flipped so do not show a mask for the correct region in an image.

How to correct this? Thank you in advance.
I am working on feature extraction using pyradiomics. I need both image and mask in NIFTI format for this purpose. But when I convert dicom image to nii image labels are not aligned. Here I provide images for reference.
[dicom images and corresponding .nii segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lEtN.png) and
[converted nii image and corresponding label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkPB.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `numpy.flip(mask, axis=0)` to flip the ground truth mask along the horizontal axis (or `axis=1` for vertical flip)?

Comment: Hi, are the labels and scans both dicom files? Do you process them in the same way? If you show us what you're doing we may be able to help.

Comment: I am working on feature extraction using pyradiomics, therfore I need both image and label in .nii format. I have images in dicom and labels in .nii format.

Comment: So the labels were never in dicom format - I think that the problem may be your s-form or q-form, which determines the direction of the images. Have you compared the `affine` matrix of your 2 nifti images (see https://nipy.org/nibabel/coordinate_systems.html)?